# PHP / Json String(20) before value

Tags: php, html, json

I currently have some json data that I am retrieving via PHP, however, my result has String(20) in front of it;

** Answer - **Var_dump causes this, just echo.**

Comment: Probably because they think, that this question could been avoided by googling or by reading the manual. Which you should definitely do before you ask any question here :) (But at the end you can't say that definitely since people are people and *people are strange animals*)

Comment: You're welcome. (FYI: A few links which might be helpful for your next question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And if you're interested in you can also read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3933332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `string(20)` is because you asked for a `var_dump()` of the item. `var_dump()` does more than echo the item, it *describes* it.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) -

> This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its **type** and **value**. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

**Extra Answer** - yes, try [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)

Comment: @Jay *Jay inception* here :D